# Curve fitting with gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, regression, curve-fitting, gradient-descent

I wrote some code that performs gradient descent on a couple of data points. 
For some reason the curve is not converging correctly, but I have no idea why that is. I always end up with an exploding tail.

Am I doing one of the computations wrong? Am I actually getting stuck in a local minimum or is it something else?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def estimate(weights, x, order):
    est = 0
    for i in range(order):
        est += weights[i] * x ** i
    return est

def cost_function(x, y, weights, m):
    cost = 0
    for i in range(m-1):
        cost += (((weights[i] * x ** i) - y) ** 2)
    return (np.sum(cost ** 2) / ( 2 * m ))

def descent(A, b, iterations, descent_rate, order):
    x = A.T[0]
    y = b.reshape(4)

    # features
    ones = np.vstack(np.ones(len(A)))
    x = np.vstack(A.T[0])
    x2 = np.vstack(A.T[0] ** 2)

    # Our feature matrix
    features = np.concatenate((ones,x,x2), axis = 1).T
    # Initialize our coefficients to zero
    weights = np.zeros(order + 1)
    m = len(y)

    # gradient descent
    for i in range(iterations):
        est = estimate(weights, x, order).T
        difference = est - y
        weights = weights + (-descent_rate * (1/m) * np.matmul(difference, features.T)[0])
        cost = cost_function(x, y, weights, m)
        print(cost)

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
    plt.plot(u, (u ** 2) * weights[2] + u  * weights[1] + weights[0], '-')
    plt.show()

A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))

b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin = 2 ).T

iterations = 150
descent_rate = 0.01
order = 2
descent(A, b, iterations, descent_rate, order)
```

I would like to avoid getting stuck in such a minimum. I have attempted setting the initial weights to random values but to no avail, sometimes it dips a bit more but then gives me the same behaviour again.

Here is the one of the plots that I am getting:
[image]

And here is the expected result obtained by a least squares solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `estimate` function should be

```py
def estimate(weights, x, order):
    est = 0
    for i in range(order+1):
        est += weights[i] * x ** i
    return est
```

Better yet, since the order information is already present in the size of the `weights` vector, remove the redundancy with:

```py
def estimate(weights, x):
    est = 0
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        est += weights[i] * x ** i
    return est
```

This is what I got when using your code and running 2000 iterations:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You probably saved me hours of frustration tomorrow morning :D Final weights [ 1.4 -1.1  0.5] it gives me the same as when using numpy's polyfit function. Also, out of curiosity, how were you able to find the error so quickly?/

Comment: Glad to know! There's no trick. I've probably made most mistakes I could possibly make in code like that. With time spotting issues becomes automatic.